# Use last added GameObject to the array/list

Tags: c#, arrays, list, unity-game-engine

I am working with C# in Unity. I have 3 different `GameObject`s in the array and I want to add the last spawned/added object to the list using an if statement like this : `If object 1 spawned then ...`
How do I make this work? Here is the code :

```
public GameObject[] arrows;
public float interval = 5;
private List<GameObject> myObjects = new List<GameObject>();

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating("SpawnArrow", 0f, interval);
}

void SpawnArrow()
{
    if (myObjects.Count > 0)
    {
        Destroy(myObjects.Last());
        myObjects.RemoveAt(myObjects.Count - 1);
    }
    GameObject prefab = arrows[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, arrows.Length)];
    GameObject clone = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(0.02F, 2.18F, -1), Quaternion.identity);

    myObjects.Add(clone);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all start with holding up the value of your random integer for the further logic ( your if statements ) :

```
void SpawnArrow()
{
    if (myObjects.Count > 0)
    {
        Destroy(myObjects.Last());
        myObjects.RemoveAt(myObjects.Count - 1);
    }
    // Here hold up the value to use in your if statement
    int randomIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, arrows.Length);

    GameObject prefab = arrows[randomIndex];
    GameObject clone = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(0.02F, 2.18F, -1), Quaternion.identity);

    myObjects.Add(clone);

    // your if statement 
    if ( randomIndex == 1 )
    {
        // your logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at using [Stacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)). This is an example of a **Last In First Out** data structure that sounds perfect if you said that want to:

> **use the last object** it spawned/added to the list

An example of using stacks:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stack stack = new Stack();

            stack.Push("First Item");
            stack.Push("Second Item");

            Console.WriteLine(stack.Pop());
            Console.WriteLine(stack.Pop());

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Second Item
First Item
```

Notice how when items are added (pushed) to the stack and then removed (popped) from the stack you will get the last item added to the stack first.

[A useful link on how to use stacks](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_stack.htm)

Comment: Data structures ftw.